# store files on s3 from local storage ckan

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, ckan

I am using ckan version 2.3 & currently using local storage.
want to stored the resouces on amazon s3 buckets using boto.
Did the configuration with production.ini file for ckan.
Not getting stored on s3 not any exceptions, errors 
on upload via GUI.

Comment: Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You may need to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your file uploads to point to s3 in config file e.g.- /etc/ckan/default/development.ini:

```
  ## OFS configuration
ofs.impl = s3
ofs.aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxx
ofs.aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxx`

  ##bucket to use in storage:
ckanext.storage.bucket = your_s3_bucket`
```

save and exit.

Run the following on the command line to migrate
from  local file storage to remote storage.

`paster db migrate-filestore`